# preg_replace with () characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to use `preg_replace` to clean a string but I want to contine with this character () - Parentheses

I'm using this code

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{Latin}\d ]/u', '', $string);
```

I want to remove everything except the parentheses letters and numbers

Comment: What do you mean, you want to continue with parentheses?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove everything except the parentheses

Comment: Use `/[^characters]/` to match everything except the specified characters.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Perhaps you could accept it now? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, use:

```
/[^\p{Latin}0-9()]/u
```

That will match anything that is not parentheses, letters or numbers.

So the full code:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{Latin}0-9()]/u', '', $string);
```

Comment: When you use a unicode character class like `\p{Latin}` or multibytes literal characters, take care to use at the same time the u modifier otherwise your character class will be seen as a set of single bytes instead of a set of potentially multi-byte characters and may cause an unwanted behaviour.